# Autocomplete SSH bash: export: `-a': not a valid identifier

Tags: command-line, bash, auto-completion

When I try to autocomplete using double TAB, I get this error:

```
bash: export: `-a': not a valid identifier
```

This mainly happens when trying to autocomplete ssh routes. However sometimes it fails to autocomplete everything. After looking around for a bit and finding out that most of the times this problem comes from bad syntax of the `export NAME=what` by having spaces around the `=` sign, I have made sure that this is not the error in my `.bashrc` file.

Any hints on what to look for?

Thank you!!

Comment: Check the file `/etc/bash_completion`, and all files in `/etc/bash_completion.d/*` and `/usr/share/bash-completion/*` for syntax errors. The command `grep -R '\bexport\b.*-a' /etc/bash_completion* /usr/share/bash-completion` might help you to find files that contain lines with the word "export" followed by "-a".